# How to make a Swiper in a component hidden in Angular work

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I want to use [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) with Angular.

The first displayed `app-child1` Swiper works normally.
The `app-child2` Swiper displayed by pressing the`child2` button does not work properly.

How do I make the `app-child2` Swiper work properly?

---

app.component.html

```
<swiper-container [options]="swipeOptions" #homeSlide>
  <swiper-slide>
    app.comp.slide1
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    app.comp.slide2
  </swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>
    app.comp.slide3
  </swiper-slide>
</swiper-container>

<hr />

<app-child1 [hidden]="isChild1"></app-child1>
<app-child2 [hidden]="isChild2"></app-child2>

<hr />

<button type="button" (click)="display1()">child1</button>
<button type="button" (click)="display2()">child2</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
isChild1 = true;
isChild2 = false;

display1() {
  this.isChild1 = true;
  this.isChild2 = false;
}
display2() {
  this.isChild1 = false;
  this.isChild2 = true;
}
```

[Repository here](https://github.com/otera/angular-slick-hidden)

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

2 things I found that are important for Swiper in our Angular App

1. Make sure you are giving each swiper slider individual ids
2. Make sure the dom has loaded before init'ing the slider so when it tries to find the slider, it's not hidden behind an *ngIf when the swiper config tries to init.